# How to Add data to MS word

Tags: delphi

I want to add some data in MSword via Delphi application. There are lots of examples available on the internet, but they are very complex. 
Can someone help me with a simple function that accept string parameter and then append that string in a word document and save that document to the desktop

Comment: It doesn't sound like you've looked very hard.  Have you tried writing any code, and where did you get stuck?  Btw, see here for a tutorial:http://www.djpate.freeserve.co.uk/AutoWord.htm

Comment: @MartynA I can't find any documentation about word automation over the internet and most of the examples on internet uses classes that I don't know. If you guide me to any documentation that would be great

Comment: You aren't making a good job of this at all. There are quadrillions of examples. Martyn even linked one. It really looks like you either aren't trying very hard, or don't know how to search.

Comment: Everything you asked for is explained in simple terms with code examples in the link provided by @MartynA. What exactly is it that you don't understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the simplest example of creating a Word document using Delphi that I can think of.  I am providing this simply to get you started, so that you can start experimenting from an example that works.  Try it, then read that tutorial I gave you the link to - I am not going to extend this answer into a tutorial.

When you start reading about automation in Delphi, you'll find that there are two ways of doing it, "early binding", where you use classes which are derived by importing the automation objects "Type Library", and "Late Binding", where you use Variants, rather than class instances, to represent the automation objects.  The example below uses late binding, because it's simplest for a basic example. Note that the special named-parameter syntax (FileName := xxx) in the argument to SaveAs

```
  Document.SaveAs(FileName := AFileName)
```

was added to Delphi to support late binding of automation objects.

Apart from tutorials like Deborah Pate's, another way to learn the basics of Delpi automation of Word is to record a Word macro that does what you want and then examine the macro's code in Word's VB editor (on the Developer tab of Word's ribbon) - usually, it's straightforward to translate the code into Delphi.

```
unit SimpleWordu;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  ComObj, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure CreateWordDoc;
  protected
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CreateWordDoc;
end;

procedure TForm1.CreateWordDoc;
var
  UserName,
  AFileName : String;
  DocText : String;
  MSWord,
  Document : OleVariant;
begin
  MSWord := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
  MSWord.Visible := True;
  Document := MSWord.Documents.Add;

  DocText := 'Hello Word!';
  MSWord.Selection.TypeText(DocText);

  UserName := 'MA';
  AFileName := Format('c:\users\%s\desktop\worddoc.doc', [UserName]);

  Document.SaveAs(FileName := AFileName);
end;

end.
```

Comment: thanks :) i have read your link and that was really helpfull.